# Why was my grammar edit rolled back?

Tags: discussion

I fixed an obvious grammar mistake in a post. The author rolled it back to the incorrect version. I thought grammar edits were encouraged since they improve the post even if in a small way. Why would a post author deliberately roll back to an incorrect version?

https://askubuntu.com/posts/222855/revisions

Comment: Who knows what people are thinking? All you can do is comment on the answer asking why they rolled it back. I would GUESS it is because you changed the meaning of a sentence slightly, "you know your going to" to "you need to" are quite different terms, the OP may think that the wording changes the intent of their answer.

Comment: I rolled it back to include your grammar fix but removed the changed wording but if the OP does not like it for whatever reason, they can revert it.

Comment: Okay I mostly wanted to clarify whether I did something distasteful or not. Perhaps there should be a checkbox for "this is a grammar edit" to bypass the minimum character restriction.

Comment: You did right, editing is a big part of the site, you just need to be a bit careful not to change peoples wording too much and sometimes people just roll things back, don't give it too much thought, it just happens from time to time..

Comment: This is the first time I've ever had a grammar edit reverted on the SE network so I came here to see if the askubuntu community perhaps felt differently about trivial edits. My goal was to _not_ change the meaning with the rewording but I clearly failed. I guess I missed some finesse. Thanks for the help!